# If Fry is technically his own Grandfather, what does that make the Professor now?

Tags: futurama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why didn't the DNA scanner find Fry to be the Professor's great^n grandfather?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/why-didnt-the-dna-scanner-find-fry-to-be-the-professors-greatn-grandfather)

If Fry is technically his own Grandfather, what does that make the Professor now? He would no longer be his nephew, correct?

Comment: What does that make the Professor? Well, angry and disgusted, I would imagine...

Answer (score 0):

The professor would be his nephew.

Answer (score 0):

He would still be his (however many) great nephew, but would also be (however many) greats + 2 greats, nephew, because he now has 2 relations to the Professor.

Comment: He would still be his Great Nephew, but would he not also be his Great Grandchild?

Answer (score 0):

He would be his great-grandfather and also be his great-nephew.